# How is a cryptographic checksum of an empty file computed?

Tags: sha1, checksum

I've just ran

```
$ sha1sum myfile
```

out of boredom.

**myfile** is an empty file which I created with

```
$ touch myfile
```

I was surprised that sha1sum actually returned a checksum. Aren't these checksums supposed to be computed from some non-empty content? Is the checksum for an empty file just a hardcoded "magic" constant?

Comment: Any hashing function starts in some well-defined initialized state, so I don't understand what bothers you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally different with an empty message from a message with say a byte of data. The algorithm is described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Examples_and_pseudocode and it's fine with zero data.

Eg.

> Pre-processing:
>
> append the bit '1' to the message append 0 ≤ k < 512  bits '0', so that the resulting message length (in bits)  is
>   congruent to 448 (mod 512)